# Making p:message draggable in PrimeFaces

Tags: primefaces

I am new to Prime Faces. I have one requirement.

I have one bean from there I'm using `showMessageInDialog(some message)`. And in JSF page, I'm using `<p:message id="someid">`.

When I run it , It opens a dialog and displays a message. Which is very fine. But my requirement is to make this box draggable. I tried a lot but couldn't. Approach I tried:

I tried to capture the id from debugger and tried to change the css : Failed
Please Help me to sort it out.

Comment: How do you define dialog to messages?

Comment: @alexSunder : I didn't define any dialog component to message. Just using p:message , and from bean showMessageInDialog . My guess , this function internally renders into something and displays dialog. When i debugged I found that p:message , id  shows as "primefacesmessagedlg" , and role="dialog" which I didn't define anywhere. So i hope primefaces is doing this.

Comment: Never see this behavior of component before. According to primefaces user guide p:message is extended standart jsf message component.  And that how it`s work in showcases http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/message/messages.xhtml Maybe i`m wrong but it seems that you are using some old version of primefaces framework. Anyway you can explicitly define p:dialog component in you pages facelets template to show messeges. And p:dialog is draggable by default.

Comment: I think u r right . Now I will try to use a p:dialog . I believe this way i can achieve my functionality .Thanks a lot anyway.

Comment: @alexSunder : please see this link http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/df/message.xhtml , If u click on show button , the box pops up , i have to make this box draggable. Exacltly same i am using.

Comment: In your case use http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/dialog/basic.xhtml To make dialog visible call RequestContext.execute(PF('messagesDialog').show();) in your howMessageInDialog() method. And set widget var for p:dialog widgetVar="messagesDialog"

Comment: @alexSunder: I didn't get what u said . How i can call execute () , inside showmessageindialog(). can u plz expalin with example.

Comment: All you need is primefaces showcase) http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/requestContext.xhtml